# How to set the field messageID in HermesJMS

Tags: jms

I try to create & send JMS messages with [HermesJMS](http://www.hermesjms.com) to a queue but the field `messageID` isn't editable...

How can I set it ?

[Screen shot: Creation of a new message in HermesJMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQW6x.jpg)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no solution to my problem...

So the best way to avoid using the default *new JMS message* feature of HermesJMS is to send a XML file of the JMS message...

Afore that you need of course to write the XML file "by hand" and define all needed fields including among others things the `messageId` field :-)